# GMSMapView didLongPressAtCoordinate: return invalid coordinate first time

Tags: ios, coordinates, google-maps-sdk-ios, long-press, gmsmapview

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
```

This delegate returns me wrong coordinates as given below and is happening only first time or i mean once you move/zoom the maps even a little bit, after that it start working fine.

This is the location i'm trying to fetch:
map's center is Latitude: 37.31486 , Longitude: -122.03122
While the delegate method return me these values: Latitude: 0.00030 , Longitude: 0.00197

Any one faced this problem or know any thing about it, your help will be much appreciated.

---Edited---
I have tested and this issue coming up when you present your view controller. Otherwise if you simply push your view controller, it works just fine.

Comment: After spending two days on this problem i have reported this bug, but for now i'm using this solution.

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = userLoction.coordinate;
    CLLocationDegrees offsetLat = 0.03;
    [mapView moveCamera:[GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord.latitude + offsetLat, coord.longitude - offsetLat)]];
}